# Passing mean of subset as argument to function in ave()

Tags: r, subset, mean

I am trying to pass the mean of a subset as an argument in the `actuar::dztpois` function.

[Package ‘actuar’ - page 133](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/actuar/actuar.pdf)

The function has the following syntax `dztpois(x, lambda, log = FALSE)`, where lambda is the mean of x. I got it as far as I can, but now I need to understand what is best practise to run a function over a subset and add arguments. From other posts, I saw that the `ave()` function is suitable, which I used successfully before but without passing arguments.

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Product = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Quantity = sample(1:100)
  )

# Winsorize data by group (Product) and add results to new column ---------
library(DescTools)
Data$Quantity_WINS <- ave(Data$Quantity, Data$Product, FUN = Winsorize)
Data$Quantity_WINS <- round(Data$Quantity_WINS)

# Calculate dtzpois value by group (Product) and add to column ------------
library(actuar)
Data$Quantity_DZTPOIS <- ave(Data$Quantity_WINS, Data$Product, FUN = dztpois)
#pass the mean of the subset as an argument in the dztpois function
```

I got the subset means but unsure whether I need to add them to the data frame or whether I can call them individually within the function; I prefer the latter.

```
Product_means <- tapply(Data$Quantity_WINS, Data$Product, mean)
```

I am not bound to the `ave()` approach but this is want I found thus far.

Comment: Simply `ave(Data$Quantity_WINS, Data$Product, FUN=function(x) dztpois(x, lambda=mean(x)))`?

Comment: @jay.sf, thanks for the quick reply and seems pretty clear to me. Is is correct, that the x in the function is already the subset ? I thought of this approach, but assumed that its taking the whole column as my x variable.

Comment: Yes, it's already the subset, just read `?ave`.

Comment: Will do again. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jay.sf suggested, amending the `ave()` function to `ave(Data$Quantity_WINS, Data$Product, FUN=function(x) dztpois(x, lambda=mean(x)))` was sufficient to fix the problem.